# Make - Nothing to be done for - only with file extension

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

I have a simple c program - hello_world.c

As you can tell by the file name i am very very new to c.

I would expect to do the following to compile:

```
make hello_world.c
```

But this gives an error message: `make: Nothing to be done for hello_world.c.`

If i just do `make hello_world` it works i.e. without the extension.

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`make` takes a target as its argument.  If you tell it you want to make `hello_word.c`, it will look, see that that file already exists and has no dependencies, and will decide it's up to date - hence nothing to do.

When you say `make hello_world`, make looks for `hello_word`, can't find it, then looks for `hello_world.o`, can't find it, then looks for `hello_world.c`, finds it, and then uses its implicit rule to build `hello_world` from it.

You can use `make -d` to see the decisions `make` is making along the way.  Here's the example for `make hello_world.c` - I've trimmed out a bunch to showcase the last part, which is what you care about:

```
...
Considering target file `hello_world.c'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `hello_world.c'.
 ...
 No implicit rule found for `hello_world.c'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `hello_world.c'.
No need to remake target `hello_world.c'.
make: Nothing to be done for `hello_world.c'.
```

Then, for `make hello_world`:

```
...
Considering target file `hello_world'.
 File `hello_world' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `hello_world'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello_world'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `hello_world.o'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello_world'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `hello_world.c'.
 Found an implicit rule for `hello_world'.
  Considering target file `hello_world.c'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `hello_world.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `hello_world'.
   ...
   No implicit rule found for `hello_world.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `hello_world.c'.
  No need to remake target `hello_world.c'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `hello_world'.
Must remake target `hello_world'.
cc     hello_world.c   -o hello_world
...
Successfully remade target file `hello_world'.
```

Comment: Oh so when i call make it is looking at the files in the current directory

Answer (score -2):

"Make" is a tool that is used to build non-trivial projects with multiple source files. If all you want to do is compile a single C file, use the C compiler. `cc` is usually available as the command-line name of the C compiler, though `gcc` is also a common name (which may refer to the same compiler).

Comment: `make` is very convenient even for single-file projects.  The implicit rules allow you to pass compiler flags easily and consistently via environment variables, for example.

Comment: We may have to agree to disagree. I'll admit that I'm pretty much an un-fan of `make` at this point.